# Cunning ways to draw a starfield

Tags: algorithm

I'm working on a game, and I've come up with a rather interesting problem: clever ways to draw starfields.

It's a 2D game, so the action can scroll in the X and Y directions. In addition, we can adjust the scale to show more or less of the play area. I'd also like the starfield to have fake parallax to give an impression of depth.

Right now I'm doing this in the traditional way, by having a big array of stars, each of which is tagged by a 'depth' factor. To draw, I translate each star according to the camera position multiplied by the 'depth', so some stars move a lot, and some move a little. This all works fine, but of course since I have a finite number of stars in my array I have issues when the camera moves too far or we zoom out too much. This is will all work, but is involving lots of code and special cases.

This offends my sense of elegance. There has got be a better way of achieving this.

I've considered procedurally generating my stars, which allows me to have an unlimited number: e.g. by using a fixed seed and PRNG to determine the coordinates. I would need to divide the sky up into tiles, generate the seed by hashing the tile coordinates, and then draw, say, 100 stars per tile. This allows me to extend my starfield indefinitely in all directions while still only needing to consider the tiles that are visible --- but this doesn't work with the 'depth' factor, as this allows stars to stray outside their tile. I could simply use multiple layered non-parallax starfields using this algorithm but this strikes me as cheating.

And, of course, I need to do all this every frame, so it's got to be fast.

What do you all reckon?

Comment: Try http://gamedev.stackexchange.com, they might have more experience with such problems.

Comment: I didn't even know that existed; ta. Any admin, feel free to move the question there...

Comment: Whatever solution you come up with, if you need more performance convert your code to use integer fix point numbers rather than floating point numbers.

Comment: interesting question, I think it belongs here on SO.

Comment: Stars should not cause parallax at all, unless all of your game objects are moving way faster than the speed of light. Of course, if you think it's cool, go for it.

Answer (score 2):

Have a few layers of stars.

For each layer, use a seeded random number generator (or just an array) to generate the amount of blank space between a star and the next one (a poisson distibution, if you want to be picky about it). You want the stars pretty sparse, so the blank space will often be more than whole row. The back layers will be more dense than the front ones, obviously.

Use this to give yourself several tiles each (say) two screens wide. Scroll the starfield by keeping track of where that "first" star is for each layer.

The player won't notice the tiling, because you scroll the tiles at different rates for each layer, especially if you use a few layers that are each fairly sparse.

Answer (score 1):

As stars in the background don't move as fast as those in the foreground, you could maybe make multi-layer tiles for the background and replace them with one-layer-ones when you've got time to do that. Oh, and how about repeating patterns in the background layers? This would maybe allow you to pregenerate all background tiles - you could still shift them in height and overlay multiple ones with random offsets or so to make it look random.

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything wrong with wrapping the star field around in X and Y?  Because of your depth, the wraparound distance should depend on the depth, but you can do that.  Each recorded star at (x,y,depth) should appear at all points

[x + j * S * depth, y + k * S * depth]

for all integers `j` and `k`.  `S` is a wraparound parameter.  If `S` is 1 then wraparound happens immediately and all stars are always shown somewhere.  If `S` is higher wraparound doesn't happen immediately and some stars are shown off screen.  You'll probably want `S` big enough to ensure no repeats at maximum zoom out.

Answer (score 0):

Each frame, render the stars on one single bitmap/layer. They are only dots, and so it will be faster than using any algorithm with multiple layers.

Now you need an infinite 2D-grid of 3D-boxes filled with a finite number of stars. For each box, you can define an individual RANDOM_SEED value, using its grid-coordinates. The stars in each box can be generated on-the-fly.

Remember to correct the perspective when you zoom: Each 3D-box has a near-rectangle (front-face) and a far-rectangle. You will see more stars of neighbouring boxes, whenever the far-rectangle or near-rectangle shrinks in your view.

Your far-rectangles should never be smaller than half the width of the near-rectangles, otherwise it might be troublesome: You might have to scan huge lists of stars where most of them are out of bounds. You can realize stars behind the far-rectangles via additional 2D-grids of 3D-boxes with other sizes and depths.

Answer (score 0):

Why not combine the coordinates of the starfield 3D boxes to form the random number seed? Use a global "adjustment" if you want to produce different universes. That way you don't need to track the boxes you can't see because the contents are fixed by their location.

Comment: The question talks about generating a "starry sky" background with a parallax effect as the view-port moves around. Not sure if this answer tackles that problem.