# Generating a Nice Looking Starfield Pattern

Tags: algorithm, sdl

I'm trying to generate a scrolling starfield for a game with C++ and SDL. I'm using a simple, naive algorithm that just creates a lot of white pixels on black backround. However, this "starfield" looks too unnatural - probably because of the random number generator's poor quality (I use the rand() function).

Are there any special algorithms for generating starfields that look more or less realistic?

Thanks.

Comment: For starters, do the stars move at slightly different speeds?

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot or something that would allow us to see in what manner the starfield is unrealistic? Or at least some more information? E.g. is your game arcade-style 2D-only? How does the scrolling happen?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Cunning ways to draw a starfield](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113111/cunning-ways-to-draw-a-starfield).

Comment: @Frustrated No, they all move at the same speed. Guess another "layer" of stars with different speed would make it look more fun

Comment: @thkala Yes, the game is a 2d scroller, and the problem is that the starfield is somewhat "regular", as if there is not enough randomness. I can't post a screenshot right now, but I'll do once I get home.

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for the link, looks like it has some useful info

Comment: @Grigory Javadyan: You want to give them slightly different speeds. Distant objects will appear to be moving slower than near objects.

Comment: I don't think you should sweat it too much if the starfield looks "regular". Hopefully people are having enough fun with the game where they don't even notice that it's repeating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this useful tutorial](http://www.krissteele.net/blogdetails.aspx?id=254) a while ago on creating a 'realistic' star field. It's not C++, but it should be easily adaptable once you get the idea.

Answer (score 3):

There's always [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20160114180422/http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/graphics/x_stars.htm) classic. Highlights:

> [...] imagine the stars to be points in 3D space, all of them moving towards the viewer, along the Z-axis. At each time step, the 3D coordinates of the stars will be projected onto the screen, and displayed.

> For a smoother effect, we can make the stars black when they first appear (so you don't notice them) then get brighter as they get closer.

> There are two ways the sense of vastness can be modeled. The first is simply to model a huge area of space, which is impractical to say the least. The second is to make the stars move with a range of velocities.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Lloyd's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_algorithm) to relax the random points and make them semi-random. I read this idea in a [map generator](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/) but it probably can be used do create an eventually distributed star field too.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want it to be truly random.  You will end up with blobs of pixels in some places when you really want individual pixels scattered around.  Your best bet would probably be to code a smaller section and then just repeat it over and over to get the full starfield look.